# Ionic Cordova AdMob Pro Error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, cordova-admob

Getting these errors on initialization.

```
error: 0, reason: Internal error, adNetwork:AdMob, adType:interstitial, adEvent:onAdFailLoad
error: 0, reason: Internal error, adNetwork:AdMob, adType:banner, adEvent:onAdFailLoad`
```

Verified the package name of the app. What could be the issue?

plugin: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

ionic example: https://github.com/jaivehall/admob-ionic-demo

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?